# Integral test for convergence: $\sum _1^\infty \frac{e^{1/n}}{n^2}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Integral test for convergence: $$\sum _1^\infty \frac{e^{1/n}}{n^2}$$

I tried approaching this as an IBP but I haven't been able to sort the solution. Can this be made into a improper integral? and if so could someone show me the process?

Comment: What are you integrating, and with respect to what? What is $n$? What are the bounds of integration?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to include the limits. I adjusted the equation.

Comment: If you know your [$p$-series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29#P-series), just use the Comparison Test; the numerator is bounded by $e$. If you don't know your $p$ series, then first show $\sum 1/n^2$ converges, using the Integral Test if you like.

Comment: I know, but I just want to see the improper integral.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to do this with the integral test, we first need to realize that the function $\dfrac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}$ is decreasing (which it is, as it has negative derivative) and is positive (which is pretty clear).

Then we may use the integral test. We consider the integral

$$\int_1^\infty \dfrac{e^{1/x}}{x^2} \mathrm{d}x.$$

We do the substitution $u = \frac{1}{x}$ to see that this is the same as

$$\int_0^1 e^u \mathrm{d}u,$$

which is clearly finite. Thus the series converges. $\diamondsuit$

Answer (score 2):

The improper integral is also straight-forward; consider
$$ I = \int_1^\infty \frac{e^{1/x}}{x^2}\,dx. $$

Let $u=1/x$, so $du=-1/x^2dx$. Therefore,
$$ I = \int_0^1 \mathrm{e}^u\,du = \mathrm{e}-1. $$
Which is, obviously, finite.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\int_1^\infty e^{1/x} \left(\frac{dx}{x^2}\right) = \int_1^0 e^u \, (-du)
$$

Or by comparison:
$$
\frac{e^{1/n}}{n^2} \le \frac{3}{n^2}
$$
and $\sum_n (3/n^2)$ converges.  But of course that is also usually shown via an integral test.